# python passing tuple as function parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know this question sounds stupid, but I just cannot get it right.

I want to start a new thread to execute this function with multiple arguments. I don't know how to get it done. There are always error here.

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=urllib2.urlopen, args=((url=REMOTE_SERVER_URL, data=context),))
thread.start()
```

The new thread would start this function.

```
urllib2.urlopen(url=REMOTE_SERVER_URL, data=context)
```

Can anyone help me? how to get it right? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples don't take keyword arguments, they're not functions. If you want to pass in keyword arguments, pass a dictionary as the `kwargs` argument:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=urllib2.urlopen, kwargs={
    'url': REMOVE_SERVER_URL,
    'data': context
})
```

Or:

```
thread = threading.Thread(
    target=urllib2.urlopen,
    kwargs=dict(url=REMOVE_SERVER_URL, data=context)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is already given above by @Blender.

But little bit of explanation for this class Thread `constructor`.

In threading module, Class Thread doesn't use any *args and **kwargs,

```
class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})
```

In the above snippet args is just an argument which default value is an empty tuple, and kwargs is another argument which default  value is empty dictionary. This is different from 
a function like `def foo(*args, **kwargs)` So, if you want to pass tuples argument please use `args` and if you want to pass dictionary argument please kwargs.

So, if you create an object like as below will run without any error, but which is wrong.

```
>>> thread = threading.Thread(target=urllib2.urlopen, args='some argument which is not tuple', kwargs='some argument which is not dict')
>>>
```

From the source code: please check the args and kwargs line, there is no unpacking there.

```
def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
             args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None):
    assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
    _Verbose.__init__(self, verbose)
    if kwargs is None:
        kwargs = {}
    self.__target = target
    self.__name = str(name or _newname())
    self.__args = args
    self.__kwargs = kwargs
    self.__daemonic = self._set_daemon()
    self.__ident = None
    self.__started = Event()
    self.__stopped = False
    self.__block = Condition(Lock())
    self.__initialized = True
    # sys.stderr is not stored in the class like
    # sys.exc_info since it can be changed between instances
    self.__stderr = _sys.stderr
```

If you don't like this answer please, let me know in comment, I will remove it.

thanks

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Thanks!